# Observables, promesas me estan volviendo loco

Tags: ionic, angular, promesas

Tengo un pequeño codigo donde leo un json para obtener la version actual Online de mis datos la idea es luego comparar con la version Local guardada con sqlite y si esta es menor entonces descargar el resto de json y actualizar mi BD.

```js
    
   this.http.get('https://mi.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.VO = data['numero'];       
        console.log(this.VO);       
      }
    );
   console.log(this.VO);
```

Se que les puede parecer una tontera pero no termino de comprender porque no puedo utilizar el valor de mi variable fuera del observable, eso significa que si o si dentro de la respuesta positiva del mismo deberia realizar la consulta de mi BD y comparar los datos o existe otra manera? con que me den una idea basica me sirve para continuar desde ya gracias

Comment: Hola Miguel, por favor lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita tu pregunta para hacer algunas mejoras (p.e. un título descriptivo, algo más de código como donde realizas la comparación y consultas la BD, etc).

Comment: Sobre la pregunta en sí, se ha hecho ya alguna como ésta. La solución es poner lo que necesites en una función y llamar a esa función como _callback_ (más o menos) cuando recibas los datos.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes utilizar la variable fuera del observable porque los observables son asincronos. En otras palabras: **No tienes manera de asegurar que una vez ejecutado la peticion get, el servidor te retornara los  datos de manera instantánea**.

Cada peticion que haces toma un tiempo en ejecutarse, tanto `get()` como `post()`. Para poder procesar los datos retornados tienes que hacerlo dentro del observable o enviar un callback que se ejecuta al momento de recibir los datos:

```
obtenerUsuarios(onrecived: (Array<Users>) => void)
{
  this.http.get('https://mi.json').subscribe(
    data => {
      onrecived(data);
    }
  );
}

// uso
obtenerUsuarios(usuarios=>{
   console.log(usuarios)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El Observer es un patron de diseño. La función de los Observables es detectar cambios, en tu caso, si otro usuario cambia la variable de tu base de datos, este detecte el cambio y se actualice automaticamente sin necesidad de refrescar la página.

Los observables tienen dos funciones (por así decirlo). El primero es el **Obsevable**, que es el que siempre esta pendiente de un cambio, siempre esta observando, valga la redundancia. El segundo es el **Suscribe**, que es el que tu pusiste arriba, ese se encarga hacer la abstración del observer, esto quiere decir que el subscribe solicita a el Observable que ejecute su función, a su vez el Observable puede llamar a el suscribe cada que detecte un cambio. Es como un tipo de promise.

Si quieres más info de esto, te dejo el link
[Oberver pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

Veo que solo pusiste la parte del **suscribe**, puedes guardar una variable en el componente y así usar la información del suscribe fuera de esta función como lo haces en tu código.

```
 this.http.get('https://mi.json').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.VO = data['numero'];       
    console.log(this.VO);       
  }
);
console.log(this.VO);
```

Puedes usar la variable *VO* para hacer las comparaciones, esta siempre va a cambiar cada que el Observable detecte un cambio (Es importante mencionar que depende donde esté el observable)